# Error while executing query for Postgresql from Qt C++

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, qt

I want to enter enter data from vector of objects into Postgresql table but it's not working. I establish connection to the database successfully, but the output returns an error -

```
QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error at end of input\nLINE 1: EXECUTE \n
```

My Code -

```
void MainWindow::WriteToDatabase()
{
//  Establishing a connection to MySQL
    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

    database.setHostName("localhost");
    database.setUserName("postgres");
    database.setPassword("1234");
    database.setDatabaseName("nz5_flightdatar");

    bool test = QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QPSQL");
    qDebug() << test << Qt::endl;

    if(database.open())
    {
        sort(FlightList.begin(), FlightList.end());

        vector<FlightData>::iterator itr;

        ui->plainTextEdit->clear();
        for (itr = FlightList.begin(); itr != FlightList.end(); itr++)
        {
            static int i = 0;
            QString Time = QString::fromStdString(FlightList[i].getTime());
            double Latitude = FlightList[i].getLatitude();
            double Longitude = FlightList[i].getLongitude();
            int Course = FlightList[i].getCourse();
            int KTS = FlightList[i].getKTS();
            int MPH = FlightList[i].getMPH();
            int AltitudeFeet = FlightList[i].getAltitudeFeet();
            QString ReportingFacility = QString::fromStdString(FlightList[i].getReportingFacility());
            i++;

            QSqlQuery query;

            query.prepare("INSERT INTO 'public.flight_data' (Time, Latitude, Longitude, Course, KTS, MPH, AltitudeFeet, ReportingFacility)"
                          "VALUES (':time', ':latitude', ':longitude', ':course', ':kts', ':mph', ':altitudefeet', ':reportingfacility')");

            query.bindValue(":time", Time);
            query.bindValue(":latitude", Latitude);
            query.bindValue(":longitude", Longitude);
            query.bindValue(":course", Course);
            query.bindValue(":kts", KTS);
            query.bindValue(":mph", MPH);
            query.bindValue(":altitudefeet", AltitudeFeet);
            query.bindValue(":reportingfacility", ReportingFacility);

            if(query.exec())
                qDebug() << "success";
            else
            {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "error", "No success");
                qDebug() << query.lastError();
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        ui->statusbar->showMessage("Writing data to Database successful", 4000);

    }

    else
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Not connected", "Unable to connect to Database");
    }

}
```

and the output -

```
qt.core.plugin.loader: In C:/Qt_Framework/6.4.1/mingw_64/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlmysqld.dll:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.13.0) [debug]
true 

QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error at end of input\nLINE 1: EXECUTE \n                ^\n(42601)")
```

I am familiar with MySQL but I went crazy today trying to install drivers but failed miserably (read document and also a lot of StackOverflow threads), so I switched to Postgresql as Qt supports QPSQL.
Kindly help if you can.

Comment: Try putting a " " (space) at the end of the first line of your SQL query `query.prepare("INSERT INTO 'public.flight_data' (Time, Latitude, Longitude, Course, KTS, MPH, AltitudeFeet, ReportingFacility) "`.  As there's no space, it may not be picking up on the _VALUES_ part and the error seems to indicate an issue with your query

Comment: tried, but did not work.

Comment: I notice from documentation that query.Prepare returns a _bool_.  Have you tried setting this to a variable and checking true / false to see if the query is being prepared successfully or not?  Also, referring to the documentation, do you need to have the _*'*_ characters surrounding your parameters?  See example here - https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#prepare

Comment: I tried to run the query without the *'* first, same error. And as I said earlier that I am using Postgresql for the first time so I opened the database from Postgresql and ran the same query. When the query was successful, I copied the query to Qt with *'* and everything.

Comment: I also tried **database.isOpen()** and **database.isValid()** functions and both returned true.

Comment: Do you know exactly where the error is being returned?  Is it right after PREPARE before the bindings?  Is it after the bindings before EXEC, or is it when you EXEC?  I would add add a couple of console outputs to try and narrow it down as the error doesn't give a lot to go on, but it does seem to indicated an issue with SQL syntax, when you're calling **EXEC**.  I also wonder if you could do a simpler query for a start just to see if you can get a **select** working first and build up from there?

Comment: I tried **query.isValid()** function in between **query.prepare()** and **query.bindValue()** and it returned false. does that help?

Comment: Possibly not, Isvalid _Returns true if the query is currently positioned on a valid record; otherwise returns false._.  Did you check to see if the result of _Prepare_ was true or false as that returns one or the other after adding your sql

Comment: Tried **bool test = query.prepare()**, it returned false. This narrows down the problem pretty well. Now we know that there is an issue with **query.prepare()** function only. Question is what is going wrong?

Comment: So now I would suggest simplifying the query to see if anything works.  May try a select query in prepare, without passing any params and see if you can get that to execute first, just to verify that works first?  Or even just do the bool check on prepare with a select query to see if it returns true

Comment: Tried running small **query.prepare()** with one parameter, and also tried it by passing **query.prepare(NULL)**. Both returned false and the same error. Maybe there is something wrong with the plugins? Maybe that is why Postgresql is unable to understand my query

Comment: What about bypassing PREPARE and pasting your query in EXEC as a param like so **query.exec("SELECT * FROM public.flight_data");**  If that yields no results, then I'm all out of ideas for now I'm afraid

Comment: Tried **query.exec("SELECT * FROM public.flight_data")* and it returned TRUE!

Comment: I noticed one thing - When I run the exact same query directly in Postgresql, it requires columns to be in **" "**. Otherwise, the query does not run.
Eg -> **INSERT INTO table("Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_n")**. But unfortunately in Qt, I am unable to do that because there is **" "** already present in the beginning and in the end when I write the **query.prepare("INSERT INTO table, (Column_1, Column_2, Column_n)")**. If I write it **query.prepare("INSERT INTO table("Column_1", "Column_2", "Column_n")")**, It throws an compilation error. This is the problem maybe!

Comment: Having to use quotation marks inside a string is not a problem; C++ has [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) (like `\"`) for that purpose.  Another way is to use so-called raw string literals starting with `R"(` and ending with `)"` (instead of the usual `"` and `"`), see the 6th syntax option on [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: @Mac if that returned true, then you're able to run a query from your code so you can rule out any issue there.  Maybe next test,try selecting a single column in EXEC, using \" as heap suggested **query.exec("SELECT \"Time\" FROM public.flight_data");**  If you can get that working and get a result of **TRUE**, you're almost there

Comment: If you are still figuring out, maybe try `query.exec()` with a minimal hard coded query to see the output.